# Authentiction issues when trying to Index SharePoint online content into GSA 7.2

Tags: search, sharepoint, office365

We are trying to index SharePoint Online content with GSA 7.2 and are running into authentication issues.  Google doesn't officially support this, but did tell me that others are doing this.

I think that we are just missing some piece of the configuration, but can't figure out what.

We are using the included SP adapter (javascript).  We can get to SPO with the user via a browser just fine, but are getting request scope is invalid or unsupported via the connector in powershell.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Marie

Comment: What is the error you are getting when you crawl SP online sites from GSA 7.2 ?

Comment: Request Scope is Invalid or Unsupported

Comment: We are now receiving " 08-24 07:06:01.626 main Application.realDaemonStart() WARNING: Failed to initialize adaptor
java.io.IOException: Cannot connect to server "https://companyonline.sharepoint.com/sites/sitelibrary" as user 'user@domain.com" with the specified password.  Please make sure they are specified correctly, and that the user has sufficient permission to access the SharePoint server.  If the SharePoint server is currently down, please try again later.  The same username/password works when access SPO via a browser

Comment: I tried with domain\user but with auditing turned on the ADFS server, that shows as domainUsername (no slash), do I need to add an extra slash?